# ImageMagick: I need an option to mirror an image to the right of itself combined into one file

Tags: user-interface, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I need to take an image and append a mirror image of itself to the right (or left). It's got to do with mapping surfaces around spheres where some surface maps do not have left and right sides that "match up". (Digression: Is there is a name for the characteristic of an image whose right and left sides can be placed next to each other, wrapped around a cylinder or sphere, seamlessly?). Appending a mirror image to itself is a quick and dirty way to fix this problem in an environment where the image is chaotic and the viewer won't notice the trick being played.

This ImageMagick command almost does the trick but the problem is, it extends the image vertically as well as horizontally but leaves the vertical extent as an empty transparency. I just want a horizontal, mirror image extension:

```
convert original.jpg -background transparent -extent 200% \( +clone -flop \) -composite mirror.jpg
```

I need the -extent option to only extend in the horizontal direction. The ImageMagick documentation doesn't cover percentage values for -extent, only ratios like -extent 4:3 or absolute dimensions like *-extent 800x600* but *-extent 200%* isn't in the documentation. Something like *-extent 200% right* is what I want. I have many images to run this transformation on and do not want to manually enter dimensions.

Comment: Use -splice with gravity of east or west as desired. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#splice

Comment: You can also use -extent with a gravity setting to force the extent only in one direction. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#extent

Comment: You can use % in geometry arguments. See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry

Comment: Nice! convert original.jpg -background transparent -extent 200%x100% \( +clone -flop \) -composite mirror.jpg worked. Thanks much.